# InjectMock does not work with RestClient for ApplicationScoped Bean in Quarkus

Tags: java, unit-testing, cdi, quarkus

After upgrading from Quarkus 1.11.3.Final to 2.2.3.Final my Unittests are failing with following message:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock - the injected bean does not declare a CDI normal scope but: javax.inject.Singleton. Offending field is cloudEventPublisherMock of test class class ch.zhaw.ba.services.order.MyTest`

This is the offending class behind the field, clearly annotated with @ApplicationScoped (not Singleton):

```
import io.cloudevents.CloudEvent;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterRestClient
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface CloudEventPublisher {

    @POST
    void publishOrder(CloudEvent cloudEvent);
}
```

This is the test I try to run:

```
@QuarkusTest
class MyTest {

    @InjectMock
    @RestClient
    CloudEventPublisher cloudEventPublisherMock;

    @Test
    void mytest() {
        //some stuff
    }
```

The CDI @ApplicationScope annotation comes from following library: `jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:jar:2.0.2`

Additionally added the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.axa.ch.trap</groupId>
    <artifactId>trap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus-plugin.version>2.2.3.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.2.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
        <cloudevents.version>2.0.0</cloudevents.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.6</jacoco.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-opentracing</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cloudevents</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudevents-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cloudevents.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cloudevents</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudevents-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cloudevents.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cloudevents</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudevents-http-restful-ws</artifactId>
            <version>${cloudevents.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.axa.ch.trap</groupId>
            <artifactId>trap-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-panache-mock</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>instrument</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>restore</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/../jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>
                                            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                                        </native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
                                        </java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
                    -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./src/main/resources/truststore_invalid.jks,-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
                </quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: can you share your pom file ?

Comment: I wonder if you use classic RESTEasy, or RESTEasy Reactive?

Comment: I added the pom. Also I'm using RESTEasy (non reactive)

Comment: Is it possible that you are overriding the scope of the rest client in your properties file ?

Comment: Oh darn... Thank you; I totally missed this config there. Weird it was set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [javier-toja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5507961/javier-toja) I totally missed following config in the application.properties:

```
ch.zhaw.ba.rest.client.CloudEventPublisher/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Singleton
```

This has overwritten the used annotation to Singleton. Seems that in 1.11.3.Final the Annotation in the code had a higher priority.