# Mocking singleton in QuarkusTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, quarkus

I want to mock RecoveryService, it's scope is @singleton.

Before the Quarkus update I was using

```
@InjectMock(convertScopes=true)
```

and it worked

Now, I try to mock it like that

```
@InjectMock
@MockitoConfig(convertScopes = true)
RecoveryService recoveryService;
```

and still getting:

> Invalid use of io.quarkus.test.InjectMock - the injected bean does not
> declare a CDI normal scope but: jakarta.inject.Singleton

Please help.

Comment: Just a guess - does Quarkus have its own `@Singleton` it wants you to use, instead of the Jakarta one?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69286048/8681) helps

Comment: It looks like you're doing everything right for the new implementation ... which I know doesn't actually help you. :)

Comment: Do you have a small reproducer somewhere? The code seems correct, so you likely found a bug.

Comment: logged a bug for Quarkus https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35080